# unable to run sonarqube in maven project

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am having the problem given below while running "mvn sonar:sonar", since i have configured using this https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/

> No plugin found for prefix 'sonar' in the current project and in the
>   plugin groups [org.sonarsource.scanner.maven,
>   org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the
>   repositories [local (C: \Users\someproject.m2\repository), central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

Exist the plugin in POM.xml file

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>${jdbc.groupId.mysql}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>${jdbc.artifactId.mysql}</artifactId>
                            <version>${jdbc.version.mysql}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: Are you setting a version for the plugin in your POM?

Comment: please check update.

Comment: Please share your pom.xml. do you have multi module maven project?

Comment: Yes, i have multi module project

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the groupId is correct, I would try:

```
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.1398</version>
```

according to https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/